# Chrome failed to start: crashed. from crontab

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cron, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a python script that uses selenium to extract some information on the web and write it to a file.
The file runs on a remote server and is executed periodically (every minute from 8:00 to 16:59) with making use of crontab. Everything seems to be working until 16:15. From then every time the script is executed from the cronjob I get the following error when initializing the webdriver:

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

The code that led up to the crash is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from datetime import datetime

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
options.headless = True
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

Searching in the web it has been suggested that it is a problem with resources (and that's why I added the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` option. And true, if I reboot the server it works again. However, this Exception only occurs when the script is started by the cronjob (after the cronjob worked flawlessly for many interations), when I run the scrip manually the Exception does not occur.
What could be the cause of this, and how do I stop it from happening?